# How can I retrieve data from database whenever I select an option in drop down list in laravel?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, laravel

How to set value to customerNumber(field from Marketing table) from database when I select an option from Request Number drop down list?

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label class="label" for="request_id">Request Number:</label>
    <select class="form-control option" id="request_id">
        <option >0 - Request Number</option>
        @foreach ($customer_requests as $customer_request)
            <option value={{$customer_request->id}}>{{$customer_request->id}} -{{$customer_request->requestNumber}} </option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>

<div class="col-sm-2">
    <label class="label" for="customerNumber" >Customer Number:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control text" id="customerNumber" name="customerNumber">
</div>
```

I am a learner of laravel and I want to know should  jQuery be used or not? And how?

```
<script>
    $("#request_id").on({
        click: function() {
        }, keypress: function() {
            $( this ).addClass( "inside" );
            var val = $(this).val();
            var data = Marketing::find(val);
            $("#customerNumber").attr("value", data[customerNumber] );

        }
    });

</script>
```

Comment: You could ajax to your controller 1st , then use Marketing::find(val) and  return the customerNumber value

Answer (score 0):

for the jquery you can try like this one:

```
$('#request_id').change(function() {
  var req_id= $(this).val();
  $.ajax({
    url:'{{url('/get/ref')}}/'+req_id,
    method:'GET',
    contentType: false,
    processData: false,
    success:function(result){
        $("#customerNumber").val(result);
    }
  });    
});
```

then, create a new controller to return customerNumber. something like:

```
public function customerNumber($req_id = 0){
  $data = Marketing::find($req_id);
  return $data->customerNumber;
}
```

Comment: thank you very much for your reply. How to call a function from ajax?